# Ldap - access for specific machines

Tags: 18.04, server, 20.04, ldap, active-directory

We have LDAP server with 300+ users-10 servers with different group. when we creating the users, every user has access of all the 10 servers. So I want to restrict the user access.
So LDAP user or LDAP user group only access the specific servers. Our users are access the servers using SSH. how to do the restrict from LDAP.

This is what I got from the internet, But this way I want to do it for each user :(
[LDAP RESTRICT SERVER LOGIN](https://thornelabs.net/posts/linux-restrict-server-login-via-ldap-hostobject-objectclass-and-host-attribute.html)

Is there any other way to implement using LDAP Groups?
I couldn't find relative information on google.
Thanks

Comment: Access HOW ? ssh? Console-Login? Web ?

Comment: @Marco Please check now, I edit the question, Users are access the servers via ssh

Comment: What about "AllowGroups" ? see `man sshd_config`

Comment: Thanks @Marco. It is working and info is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for info @Marco

When I added the AllowGroups in sshd_config, I got the errors like invalid credentials.

```
pam_ldap: error trying to bind as user "cn=test user,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" (Invalid credentials)
```

This error is pop up because pam_groupdn is not enabled and pam_member_attribute.

Changed the setting in /etc/ldap.conf
Enable  the pam_groupdn  and pam_member_attribute

```
pam_groupdn

# Group to enforce membership of
#pam_groupdn cn=PAM,ou=Groups,dc=padl,dc=com

pam_member_attribute

#pam_member_attribute uniquemember
```

Then added the AllowedGroups in sshd_config

it is working as expected.

Note: Add your sudo users or group in AllowGroup or AllowUser, else you will get blocked for sudo access.